# Why Heroku server is not fetching APIs? (PERN stack)

Tags: heroku

I need help debug this problem. My app is in React, Node, Express and Postgres. I deployed it successfully on Heroku and the webpage showed static pages perfectly. But it went blank for the portion where it needs to fetch data from APIs. When I did Heroku logs, it gave me the error like below. Could anyone help me debug this problem?

```
2021-03-04T21:53:41.073745+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
2021-03-04T21:53:41.073746+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
2021-03-04T21:53:41.073746+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
2021-03-04T21:53:41.073746+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
2021-03-04T21:53:41.073747+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-03-04T21:53:41.073997+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2021-03-04T21:53:41.074202+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2021-03-04T21:53:41.774057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-04T21:54:14.053381+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/v1/games" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=02a42e4d-25b9-48c2-acc5-6de49e004d26 fwd="49.36.161.255" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-04T21:54:14.958989+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=08805f36-0075-4a07-86f6-656dee3b408e fwd="49.36.161.255" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=57ms status=200 bytes=4179 protocol=https
2021-03-04T22:08:59.957742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=63a022a5-3e96-486b-8e11-15f7e566b641 fwd="54.212.47.199" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=5654 protocol=https
2021-03-04T22:44:57.037070+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-03-04T22:44:57.064406+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-03-04T22:45:00.490306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-03-04T22:45:00.698397+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-03-04T23:43:50.795940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2021-03-04T23:43:50.811189+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-03-04T23:44:02.112382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2021-03-04T23:44:04.893222+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started on port 49627!
2021-03-04T23:44:04.893233+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911897+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "54.210.219.228", user "jlffntexskqxaf", database "d1dni4rrpqm6k3", SSL off
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911901+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911901+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911903+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911903+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911905+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911905+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911907+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911908+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911908+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.911908+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.914751+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2021-03-04T23:44:04.914952+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2021-03-04T23:44:05.498199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-04T23:44:06.470124+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=45919086-26e2-4c1a-aff1-eda45e1f933e fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=24ms status=200 bytes=2731 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:06.584547+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.5af4f64f.chunk.css" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=8e202985-8dfb-474e-991e-1d89d39c5fc3 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=2279 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:06.618133+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.8bd4d093.chunk.js" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=6ca3ad78-5d12-4b6a-ac01-af1ad1e9384d fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=28ms status=200 bytes=383646 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:06.675395+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.4cf487f4.chunk.js" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=1d80558f-6431-4956-aee4-5dc42b8310d0 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=45167 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:06.744820+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=70bd397b-af31-452b-bafb-1707c2b03a2e fwd="3.80.210.39" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=2731 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:06.782064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=5a81f9b3-4dcc-4e63-b28e-542c2c794f4c fwd="3.237.171.154" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=5654 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:06.877220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=d515b78f-58ec-4bbf-8874-ae492f6b9513 fwd="3.234.144.228" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=206 bytes=2778 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:07.171785+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.4cf487f4.chunk.js.map" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=69fed97b-2746-4914-b977-be2668ef3b0f fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=69547 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:07.176380+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=dc7e6a55-1b29-431e-bf77-fe46964afce9 fwd="34.214.111.232" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=5654 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:07.225223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.8bd4d093.chunk.js.map" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=f4ec6f15-0c34-42ed-af11-e3a012a9b260 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=58ms status=200 bytes=971615 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:07.273221+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=12931599-168f-473f-95d0-14f496f31942 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=819 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:07.290872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=ce501ba5-8e6a-48bf-8ccd-b785c8a66e9d fwd="18.202.25.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=5654 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:07.354782+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/turtles.7ea6de07.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=7552a395-f657-40bf-ac50-b4844b90b843 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=21948 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:07.410937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.5af4f64f.chunk.css.map" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=c7e4dc6a-ba09-473e-a09b-37dbf1c5e37e fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=4300 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:07.552424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=53a16618-8367-48ca-ac19-7d339ce403b1 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=4179 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:07.553262+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=b37b12cf-e6e4-482b-9621-772e31d1389c fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:07.649501+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=6edc1a66-ac52-4837-b9d8-43378c27a0c3 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=5654 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:37.183194+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/v1/games" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=113762b3-be0c-4ac2-aa11-dc37b3218194 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:44:37.335666+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/v1/tasks" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=537069ed-4a83-4257-bcdb-0556b12b39f7 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:52:11.484328+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=cbd8eeec-35b3-4de4-a454-b3cd8210b515 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:52:11.614284+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.5af4f64f.chunk.css" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=acd6c458-f33f-46a6-957e-d539f91be93a fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:52:11.622980+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.8bd4d093.chunk.js" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=6612dca1-351f-40ba-b520-a2d4d960bc29 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:52:11.697104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.4cf487f4.chunk.js" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=cdbeb449-7314-4b61-bdbb-dd9adfb5c195 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:52:11.856163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/turtles.7ea6de07.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=0323139b-e553-46f3-b310-b65f490b4f85 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:52:12.240896+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=7383108f-868f-4b10-951c-2ec0b3fe6fba fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:52:12.342121+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=26d06480-6587-4689-9bd5-dd9762a5b08f fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:52:41.848910+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/v1/games" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=e20483a2-a40c-4cd0-853e-3a83abbbe4e3 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:52:41.857343+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/v1/tasks" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=f715ed11-468f-4441-acdf-e8a7b65e89d3 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:54:20.482564+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=d9fd649d-a11e-410b-ba7f-4dc7966f7a66 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:54:20.622682+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.5af4f64f.chunk.css" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=27075272-c9f6-4121-868d-e5676145f2fd fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:54:20.627330+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/2.8bd4d093.chunk.js" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=b599d46a-5afd-43e4-876f-1b20bd37260b fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=271 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:54:20.709402+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.4cf487f4.chunk.js" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=e20dfa9a-2790-4db0-8459-e0c3fb833868 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:54:20.871471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/turtles.7ea6de07.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=f4fa7a17-0da0-4c1c-8983-8f6ace58a010 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:54:21.267283+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=2676a096-1f30-4b69-a4a2-db50a463cd36 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=269 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:54:21.355716+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=30618fa1-e31d-4112-8c96-5016efa6d735 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=270 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:54:50.868570+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/v1/games" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=f874099a-875f-4e39-95f0-edb3d38160de fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30011ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:54:50.869152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/api/v1/tasks" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=ffa15ae5-92d2-4e52-a193-7397620e7508 fwd="68.228.82.153" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-05T00:18:25.153805+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=8592c662-8dab-483d-aea6-384a4dbd2a00 fwd="52.211.163.136" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=5654 protocol=https
2021-03-05T00:51:35.847518+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-03-05T00:51:35.850202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-03-05T00:51:36.770090+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-03-05T00:51:36.894779+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-03-05T01:04:39.125354+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2021-03-05T01:04:39.248383+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-03-05T01:04:47.571627+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2021-03-05T01:04:49.520038+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started on port 17992!
2021-03-05T01:04:49.520052+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527741+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "18.212.217.163", user "jlffntexskqxaf", database "d1dni4rrpqm6k3", SSL off
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527742+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:278:15)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527742+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527743+00:00 app[web.1]: at Parser.parse (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527743+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:10:42)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527744+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527744+00:00 app[web.1]: at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527745+00:00 app[web.1]: at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527745+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527746+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527746+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.527866+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
2021-03-05T01:04:49.528003+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
2021-03-05T01:04:49.721930+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-05T01:04:51.340564+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=nteract-games.herokuapp.com request_id=618aa02a-aa62-468d-a058-8501f4258b46 fwd="52.37.199.84" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=22ms status=200 bytes=5654 protocol=https
2021-03-05T01:40:21.938163+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-03-05T01:40:21.944094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-03-05T01:40:23.121294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-03-05T01:40:23.257393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Comment: As the error shows, it is in some promise, as you mentioned. Please upload that portion of code which handles promises. Your promise is giving some error but you are not handling that.

Comment: Also, I noticed this error (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "54.221.109.181", user "jlffntexskqxaf", database "d1dni4rrpqm6k3", SSL off

Comment: I wonder if my config.js or db.js is not set up correctly.

Comment: Are you making multiple API calls at once. If not then you can simply check the code block which is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has a new requirement as of February 23, 2021: [All Heroku Postgres client connections require SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2035). We didn't get an email warning us about this before it happened, so our app suddenly went offline. I was able to fix it by making the following updates to our Heroku app config variables:

- Set `PGSSLMODE` to `require`
- Set `DB_USE_SSL` to `true`

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)